# What are the characteristics of an ideal data frame from a programing point of view?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-structures, statistics, data-science

I know that data frame is a form of data structure. Regardless of a programming language that can be used to model it, what should be the bare minimum characteristics of an ideal data frame?